# flutter ListView returning 'hasSize' error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-test

I am using list view to build my flutter list. the code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Expanded(
  child: Container(
    color: kMainColor,
    child: Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          controller: _scrollController,
          children: [
            Text("ff"),
            Text("ff"),
            Text("ff"),
            
          ],
        ),
       ]
      )
    )
  );
 }
}
```

but I get this error :

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#b8187 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

I don't know what this error is and what is causing it. I tried to wrap the listView in Container and give it a height it also returned an error. what can I do to fix it?

Comment: HI There. This is most likely caused due to some constraints that the `Stack` is getting from it's parent. So post your entire widget code.

Comment: You cannot have a `ListView` inside a `Stack` because Stack doesn't constrain its child. Since a `ListView` takes as much height as it could get, it will expand infinitely inside `Stack` because it doesn't constrain the `ListView`'s height.

Comment: what do you recommend I do?

Comment: Remove the "Expanded" Widget.

Comment: The piece of code you shared is working with some warnings(to remove Expanded widget). You need to share remaining code from where this widget is getting called to get answer for the error.